# Recurrence relation and time complexity of recursive factorial

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

I'm trying to find out time complexity of a recursive factorial algorithm which can  be written as:

```
fact(n)
{
 if(n == 1)
 return 1;
 else
 return n*fact(n-1)
 }
```

So I write the recurrence relation as

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1)
```

Which is correct according to this post: [Recurrence relation of factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379929/recurrence-relation)
 
And I calculate the time complexity using substitution method as follows:

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1)  // Original recurrence relation
= n * (n-1) * T(n-2)
...
= n * (n-1) * ... * 1
= n!
```

But according to this post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373065/complexity-of-factorial-recursive-algorithm), both recurrence relation and time complexity are incorrect.
 
What am I doing wrong or not getting correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of how recursive code maps to a recurrence is flawed, and hence the recurrence you've written is "the cost of T(n) is n lots of T(n-1)", which clearly isn't the case in the recursion. There's a single recursive call, and a multiplication of the result.

Assuming the numbers aren't large, the multiplication is constant time, and it's a single operation, not a multiplier on the number of recursive calls:

$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + c_{1}
$$

The base case is $T(1) = c_{2}$

If we simplify things further, and assume $c_{1} = c_{2} = 1$ (it makes no difference to the final asymptotic analysis anyway), you get:

$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 = T(n-2) + 1 + 1 = T(n-2) + 2 ...
$$

And the same final result as [the StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373065/complexity-of-factorial-recursive-algorithm) of $T(n) = n$.

Comment: Thanks Luke, but can you shed some light on the accepted answer of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379929/recurrence-relation is it any correct?

Comment: Both parts of that answer are correct. The first part describes the *running time* of the algorithm to compute $n!$, as Luke just did. The second part describes the *value* of $n!$

Comment: All of this, assuming unit cost arithmetic.

Comment: @RickDecker does it mean that the recurrence relation in my question gives upper bound on **value of 'n'** and the answer of LukeMathieson gives upper bound on **time complexity of function**?

Comment: @Breakpoint. Yup. To be more precise, the recurrence relation in your question gives the exact value of the function on input $n$ and Luke's gives the time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$T(n) = n * T(n-1)$$ compute $n!$ in recursive manner, is differ from running time of your algorithm, hence $T(n)$ is recursive formula for compute $n!$.

If $f(n)$ be the time complexity of your algorithm, so

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+O(1).$$

Note that, if we change your recursive code as follow:

```
 fact(n)
    {
     if(n == 1)
     return 1;
     else
     for i=0 to n
     x=x+n*fact(n-1);
     return x;
     }
```

then $f(n)$ will be

$$f(n)=nf(n-1)+O(1).$$

Comment: No, your algorithm has the same complexity as the original one: once the first return statement in the loop executes, the function, well, *returns*, skipping the rest of the loop.

Comment: If you want something sensible with $\Omega(n!)$ running time, try `fact(n) { if(n == 0) return 1; r = 0; for i=1 to n  r = r + fact(n-1); return r;  }`

Comment: And now, besides x being uninitialized, it does not compute $n!$ anymore, but $(n+1)!n!/2$. The correct code is in my comment above.